# Using loop with IIf in Access query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to calculate a field in an Access 2010 query that takes the number in volumes and either uses the default URL (for values of 1) or loops as many times as there are volumes to create a series of URLs (it's OK if they're all together, it will be text output in a report in the end).

If 1 volume, http://blah.com/1. If 2 volumes, http://blah.com/2/vol1, http://blah.com/2/vol2 .

I was thinking of something like this:

```
=IIf([volumes]="1",[URL],for i=1 to [volumes] output [URL] & "/vol[i], " next)
```

but I can't figure out if I need a variable for volumes or how to assign it or how to generated the output. Any advice on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

```
URL                 Item    volumes
http://blah.com/1   Book1   1
http://blah.com/2   Book2   2
http://blah.com/3   Book3   10
```

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop will do:

```
Public Function PrintUrlVol(ByVal Url As String, ByVal Volume As Integer) As String

    Dim UrlList As String
    Dim Index   As Integer

    If Volume = 1 Then
        UrlList = Url
    ElseIf Volume > 1 Then
        For Index = 1 To Volume
            If UrlList <> "" Then
                UrlList = UrlList & ", "
            End If
            UrlList = UrlList & Url & "/vol" & CStr(Index)
        Next
    End If

    PrintUrlVol = UrlList

End Function
```